# <th> width issue

Tags: html

I can't change the width size of my `<th>`. Is it possible to force the table to keep everything inside a `<th>` in one line? If I set width 100% on them nothing happens

Something like min-width:100px <-- which is AUTO

So it's on one line and enabled horizontal scroll

Comment: Not much to show its just a table with normal table header's that are getting small to the size of the screen width, when i set the table to overflow it still does not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forcing everything to be one one line is done with `white-space:nowrap`.

Take note though: in a table, every width depends on widths of things elsewhere in the table, so you must be on the lookout for surprises. That said, `width:100%` should definitely do something, even if it may not be what you expect. We need some of your code to tell you more.

Comment: Thank you, already answered it with white-space:nowrap, will accept in 6 minutes

Comment: OK. You do know that a width in percentages means a percentage of the _available width_, right? So if you have a table with two columns and you set each to width:100%, each column will be as wide as the screen, and the table will be twice the width of the screen. Things like that. If you know all that, but it still doesn't work as you expect, we'll still need to see your HTML.

Comment: Yeah just realised that, and that was my issue... It was set to 100% so it was taking the size of the screen. But with white-space:nowrap seems to work perfectly thanks